# Finding interior regions in figure

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic

Let's say we have a dark donut on a white background. What is a good way, looking only at any pixel's value (0 = not white, 1 = white) and any neighbouring pixel values, to determine which one of the two white regions found on the image is inside the donut?

[image: Dark Donut]
<sub>(source: [123rf.com](http://us.cdn2.123rf.com/168nwm/aaronamat/aaronamat1011/aaronamat101101843/8326944-bite-chocolate-donuts-on-a-white-background.jpg))</sub>

Comment: @talonmies Is there another Stack site this would be more suited for?

Comment: How is this off-topic? It's practical, it's answerable, and it asks about a specific programming problem or algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In computer graphics, this problem has been extensively studied in the context of geometry processing. The goal is to know whether a point is outside or outside a polygon (possibly with holes), and has been used for color filling for example.

The most common solution is to throw a line in a random direction from your current point (for simplicity, you can take an horizontal scan line), and count the number of intersections with the boundary. If this number is even, you are outside, and if it is odd, your are inside.

In the context of image processing, finding the boundary can be done with edge finding techniques (for instance, the Sobel operator). You can now just walk on a single row from your given point to the right (for instance) and count how many edges you found.

Answer (score 3):

WhitAngl's answer is correct, so my answer is simply bringing in context some problems involved in Image Processing. If you are aware of these, sorry for the naïveness.

Given your initial image, simply considering its edges is bound to give incorrect results due to the own problems of detecting edges. They might be broken, they might not be detected, etc.. Also, from your own considerations, we cannot simple use 0 = not white, 1 = white. With your original image, this is the result of such consideration:

[image]

If we suppose you have a better binary representation as this one:

[image]

Then WhitAngl's answer applies perfectly. Also, in this case, the answer can be simplified to: if there is a black pixel of the exterior edge touching a white pixel, then this white pixel is not an interior one. This gives:

[image]

Where every white pixel is interior to your donut.

Comment: There is the edge case where the black object has 1-pixel-wide edges. If you consider a pixel as a square (in 2D rectangular grid) and you can define its outer part and inner part, this is solved. In Images this is usually easy, as we could consider the pixel at top left corner (we could even extend the image if necessary) as a background pixel.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanations!